# Data Structure for implementing simple table? Array vs structure?

Tags: arrays, structure

Data Structure for implementing simple table: Array vs structure?

What structure will you use if you want create a simple table? Explain Why?

OPTIONS:

1. Structure
2. Array?

Comment: What do *you* think is the right answer, and why?

Comment: What programming language is this question about? Haskell? Clojure? Prolog? Brainfuck? A Turing machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs from the table. As I understand, you just want to implement a simple table with few columns.

If you know how many rows you have, you can allocate an array of your desired size. But how do you want to implement each row? If it is a simple integer than you are ok with the array. Else, you need to use struct for your row. Than it would be an array of pointers where each pointer points you to your struct that represents the table row.

If your table is not static and need to support insertion and deletion of rows, I would creat a linked list. Each row would be implemented inside a struct, and every struct would have a field telling me who is the next row struct (node in list).

Comment: I wanted a simulation of our Table and what i think after your solution that i should use Structure for INSERTION and stuff !! M i right ?

Comment: Thank You for suggestion !!

Comment: @SurajJorwekar I believe you are right. If it was helpful, I'll appreciate if you'll accept my answer.